# Cannot add App_Data SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio  2010 10.0.20319.1 RTMRel and SQL Server Express 10.50.1600.1 I'm trying to add a new SQL Server Database .mdf, however, I receive the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network
>   Interfaces, error: 25 – Connection
>   string is not valid)

I have enabled TCP/IP and Named Pipelines, added Firewall Exceptions for Sql Server, I am successfully connecting from VS in the  Server Explorer window.

I would appreciate if someone can pint me to a solution to my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: The error says that your connection string is not valid.  So, check your connection string.  If you're not sure what to look for, then post your connection string.

Comment: I start blank, I do not have any connection string set up; none that I know of anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think that SQL Server must be running locally to be able to create those databases.

- I was getting the same error
- Started my local .\SQLEXPRESS instance
- no more error, and a cute .mdf file was created

Comment: I cannot verify the answer anymore, but I'll give a plus :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your error

> (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,
>   error: 25 – Connection string is not
>   valid)

check here what your connection string should look like

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008